# .htaccess : Location not allowed here

Tags: apache, web-applications, apache-config, httpserver

I am getting a "Location not allowed here" error with this `.htaccess`.

Does anyone have any idea on how I should fix this?

```
<Files 'login'>
    AuthName NTLM
    AuthType NTLM
    NTLMAuth on
    NTLMAuthoritative on
    NTLMServer <censored>
    NTLMBackup <censored>
    NTLMLockfile <censored>
    require valid-user
    Satisfy all
</Files>
<Location /alarms/[0-9]+/acknowlege>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from localhost
</Location>
```

Comment: Where are you with this?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`Location` isn't valid in `.htaccess`

See:

- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#location
- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#files

Notice how `Files` says that you can have it in `.htaccess`, but `Location` doesn't... You'll need to add your `Location` to either the server config or a virtual host.